# Driver mount.ntfs-3g is using way to much cpu

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, ntfs

ATM I'm downloading a movie with deluge which is 12GB big.

This is a single .mkv file but the weird thing is that when I download this and I use NTFS-3G to mount my USB to debian it uses 99% of my CPU with 1MB/s while my CPU is a 1.7Ghz Quad Core (ODROID-U2).

It runs on debian / linux.

Anyone any idea's what the problem might be?

Hope you guys can help :)

Edit:

How to set the block size in linux? I changed the block size with formatting but that didn't change anything

Comment: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#highcpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the block size was 4kbytes and that that probably caused it with really big files, moved up the 32 solved the problem. I do recommend 64 though if you only use it for downloading 5+GB files..

Comment: This required formatting the disk, I take it?

Comment: Yes! sorry for the late reply